# System.security.NoAccessException: Update access denied for Name, controller action methods may not execute

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created custom 'Create PDF' button in Quote using VF page. When I try to send email, I'm getting error

> "System.security.NoAccessException: Update access denied for Name,
>   controller action methods may not execute"

But we are not updating anything and also checked with permissions.

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
public PageReference sendEmail() {
    List<String> toAddresses = toAddress.split(';');   
    List<String> ccAddresses = new List<String>();
    List<String> bccAddresses = new List<String>();   

    PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/QuoteTemplate?id='+quote.Id);
    Blob body;

    if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
        body = blob.valueOf('Unit.Test');
    } else {
        body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
    }

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()) { 
        efa.setFileName(quoteDocumentName);
    }
    else {
        efa.setFileName('quoteDocument.Name');
    }
    efa.setBody(body);

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    //email.setTargetObjectId(quote.id);
    email.setWhatId(quote.Id);
    email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    if(ccAddress != null && ccAddress.trim() != ''){
        ccAddresses = ccAddress.split(';',0);
        email.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
    }
    if(bccAddress != null && bccAddress.trim() != ''){
        bccAddresses = bccAddress.split(';',0);
        email.setBccAddresses(bccAddresses);
    }

    email.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] result = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

    PageReference recordPage = new PageReference('/'+quote.Id);
    return recordPage;   
}
```

Comment: Try updating apex class without sharing

Comment: Can you probably post your code as well?

Comment: @kurunve Hello, thanks for the response i edited the question and inserted the class please have a look.

Comment: @RashmiS thank you for response, we already tried that it is not working.

Comment: Hi @SuyashAkhileshDeshmukh, can you check whether your Visualforce page is set to readOnly="true"?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to update the field Name, but you do not have edit + read permissions. I do not see in your code from which object the field Name is coming from. Try to find out which object the field Name belongs to, then grant to that object edit and read permissions. For granting permission go to setup > profiles > select your profile > Standard Object Permissions.

Comment: @Cubancoffee we are system administrator, we have all the permissions and we are not updating anything, we used custom button with visualforce page which consist of send and save email button.

Comment: Hi @SuyashAkhileshDeshmukh, there might be a trigger, workflow rule or whatsoever that tries to update the Name field. Can you enable the logs and look for DML_BEGIN? Please, share the results if any.

Comment: @Cubancoffee there is no DML_BEGIN in the logs.